# Convert array of hashes and symbols into unique

Tags: ruby

I have this array `[{:foo=>[{:bar=>[:baz]}]}, :foo, {:foo=>[{:bar=>[:bat]}]}, :bar]`
As you can see there are symbols and hashes. What I am trying to do is avoid repetition for each key or keys inside values.
My desired output is :

```
[{:foo=>[{:bar=>[:baz, :bat]}]}, :bar]
```

As you can see, there's no repetition of key foo or repetition of foo=>bar.

I've been stuck for hours on this one and I cannot achieve it. Any idea?

Comment: Recursive iteration through hash values would _almost_ do. The thing is the problem as is stated **has no solution**. Think of `{foo: [:bar]}, {foo: {bar: [:baz]}}`.

Comment: Yeah, it's exactly what it happens to me. I almost get it but never comes up the final solution.

Comment: May be my problem is at the moment that I am building this specific array, because I'm coming from an array("foo.bar.baz, foo,  foo.bar.bat, bar")

Answer (score 0):

The below would somehow work:

```
input = [{:foo=>[{:bar=>[:baz]}]},
         :foo,
         {:foo=>[{:bar=>[:bat]}]},
         :bar]

builder = ->(value, acc = {}) {
  case value
  when Hash
    value.each_with_object(acc) do |(k, v), acc|
      builder.(v, acc[k] ||= {})
    end
  when Array
    value.each_with_object(acc) do |v, acc|
      builder.(v, acc)
    end
  else acc[value] ||= {}
  end
}
```

The above already produces more or less acceptable result:

```
puts (built = builder.(input)).inspect
#⇒ {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>{}, :bat=>{}}}, :bar=>{}}
```

To return exactly what you wanted one needs to chain lambdas (there is no way to tell in advance whether the object is a leaf or not):

```
fixer = ->(acc) {
  result = acc.all? { |*v| v.last.empty? } ? acc.keys : 
    acc.map { |k, v| v.empty? ? k : { k => fixer.(v) } }
  result.size == 1 ? result.first : result
}

puts fixer.(built).inspect
#⇒ [{:foo=>{:bar=>[:baz, :bat]}}, :bar]
```

I believe it’s up to you to play with this code to manage it to suit your needs better.

Comment: Merci mudasobwa. Ho provaré mes tard! Abraçada des de Barcelona

Comment: De nada! / De res!